# How to resolve "Commands out of sync" Error?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code snippet where I try to execute two Mysqli prepared statements. Unfortunately, I can get **only** the result set of the first prepared statement. I tried to troubleshoot this by identifying where the error is coming from by echoing:

```
 $noError = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);

 if(!$noError)
  {
    echo "Error:<br/>" . mysqli_error($con);
  }
```

and I got this:
**Error:
Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now**

*The code snippet*:-

```
 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
 $stmt2 = mysqli_stmt_init($con);

 mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'select fname,city from member where mid=?');
 mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt2,'select paying_date,amount from fees where 

mid=?');

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i',$MID);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2,'i',$MID);

 for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++)
 {
  $MID = $i;


  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);



  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$fname,$city);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2,$paying_date,$amount);



  mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2);

  echo $fname." ".$city." ".$paying_date." ".$amount."<br/>"; 
 }
```

So, how do I get rid of this error? With thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, after some more research I got the answer on my own, but sadly, there are some ***insane*** people who instead of providing any clue or hint, just downvote the question. So, I decided to answer myself. The code *snippet* now becomes:

```
 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
 $stmt2 = mysqli_stmt_init($con);

 mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'select fname,city from member where mid=?');
 mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt2,'select paying_date,amount from fees where 

mid=?');

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i',$MID);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2,'i',$MID);

 for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++)
 {
  $MID = $i;

  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$fname,$city);
  mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2,$paying_date,$amount);
  mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2);
  echo $fname." ".$city." ".$paying_date." ".$amount."<br/>";

 }
```